# How to access particular Key-Value pair in java script object having a json string

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, handlebars.js

I am using handlebars.js to generate and fill a table rows dynamically .

**The template code is**

```
<script id="row-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
{{#each .}}
<tr>
                        <form class="form-inline">
                        <td><label class="" id ="workerid">{{worker_id}} </label></td>
                        <td><a href="" id ="workerName">{{worker_name}}</a> </td></tr>
{{/each}}
</script>
```

**The Javascipt code is**

```
var dataFinal = JSON.stringify(result);
var d1 = eval('(' + dataFinal + ')');
var tmpScrpt = $("#row-template").html();
var tmp = Handlebars.compile(tmpScrpt);
var html = tmp(d1);
$("#tablerowid").html(html);
```

**The value of object d1 is**

```
Object {d: "[{"worker_id":1,"worker_name":"Shivank"}]"}
```

I am unable to get worker_id in the template rendered html.

How to access them in the template script for eg {{d.worker_id}}

Please Help .

Comment: I am asking about how to access them in the template script for eg {{d.worker_id}}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a mistake in the template, see the each block in the [handlebars.js documentation](http://handlebarsjs.com/builtin_helpers.html)

Use `{{#each d}}` instead of `{{#each .}}`

**Working Code:**

```js
$(function() {
  var d1 = {
    d: [{
      "worker_id": 1,
      "worker_name": "Shivank"
    }]
  }
  var tmpScrpt = $("#row-template").html();
  var tmp = Handlebars.compile(tmpScrpt);
  var html = tmp(d1);
  $("#tablerowid").html(html);
})
```

```html
<script data-require="handlebars.js@1.3.0" data-semver="1.3.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.3.0/handlebars.js"></script>
<script data-require="jquery@3.0.0" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>

<script id="row-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{#each d}}
  <tr>
    <form class="form-inline">
      <td>
        <label class="" id="workerid">{{worker_id}}</label>
      </td>
      <td><a href="" id="workerName">{{worker_name}}</a> 
      </td>
  </tr>
  {{/each}}
</script>
<div id="tablerowid"></div>
```

Comment: the object is this  {d: "[{"worker_id":1,"worker_name":"Shivank"}]"}

you have taken {
    d: [{
      "worker_id": 1,
      "worker_name": "Shivank"
    }]
  }

Comment: how to properly parse it into js object .....pls help me on this ....thanks in advance

Comment: you can use JSON.parse method,or js eval

Comment: the strings doesn't have a properly structure ,this is the correct one {"d":[{"worker_id":1,"worker_name":"Shivank"}]}

Answer (score 5):

```
alert(d1.d[0].worker_id);
alert(d1.d[0].worker_name);
```

Comment: I was asking about how to access them in the template script 
for eg {{d.worker_id}}